# How to boot Windows XP using the image file(not the extracted image file)

Tags: multi-boot, iso-image, usb-flash-drive

Is it possible to boot from an iso image file itself. Because when you burn it, it gets extracted.
Because in linux you can just place the .iso file in a removable media and boot from it without extracting. Is it possible to make something like that in windows?
What I'm saying is related to this:
http://wintoflash.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=312

Something like creating a flash drive which has the ability to install multiple os.
They have something like this in pendrivelinux but I can't find it anymore. 
But that boot manager can only install linux. And other live cd's used in cleaning the system.

That's why I'm asking if its possible to make a custom windows xp or windows 7 installer so that the image file alone can boot.

Comment: technically, when you burn the ISO, the data in the ISO file is laid down on the cd/dvd exactly as it is in the file.  that's not an extraction; that's a filesystem.  to boot from an ISO, you have to have a bootloader that can load nested filesystems (so it can find the ISO file on the flash drive's main filesystem, then read the ISO contents from the ISO's filesystem).  it's easier just to extract the files from the image so you don't have to deal with nested filesystems in the bootloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do it with [UNETBOOTIN](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: UNETBOOTIN extracts the image file. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.